# Split text into different columns in csv

Tags: linux, csv, text-processing

I have all data in first column in csv file delimited comma. How can I split data into different columns (I mean every word separate by comma should be in different cells).

Input (shows A column in excel ):

> ```
> name,age,city
> john,21,london
> michael,25,sydney
> ```

Output: A1 column contain name, B1 contain age, C1 city, A2 john etc

Please explain which command I need to use in linux

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to *extract*  column info or just want to *reformat* a text file. You have shown no effort and no code. I'm sorry but this kind of question if off topic on this site. You really should read [ask] and edit the question with the minimal required information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for simply replacing commas with pipe you can use below:

```
sed 's/,/|/g' filename.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *column* command like:

```
column <filename>
```

or

```
column -c20 <filename>
```

use *help* to findout more option:

```
column --help
```

source is here: https://www.lifewire.com/file-contents-in-column-format-linux-4018107

(I test this commands on Linux ubuntu 17.04)

Answer (score 0):

In such cases is convenient to make a script instead a command line and use a specific function that formats the output in a given style; then use it for different lines.

Here's a solution in perl exactly processing as the question asks:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 my $myformat="%-30s%5s%-30s%5s%-30s\n"; 
 my $pad="-"x30; 

 sub myprint {
     my $format = shift;
     my $separator = shift;
     my @final;
     foreach my $x (@_) {
        push(@final,$x,$separator);
     }
     pop @final; # delete last separator
     printf $format,@final;
 }

 my $l=0;
 while(<>) {
    chomp; 
    next if($_ eq "");
    $l++; 
    myprint($myformat,"  |  ",split(/,/));  
    if($l==1) { 
        myprint($myformat,"--|--",$pad,$pad,$pad);
    }
}
```

then use it:

```
# cat my_input_file.txt | perl myscript.pl
```